# Bitcoin Gold wallet/ miner

Tags: wallet, mining-hardware

I have my Bitcoin Gold wallet up and running and have my BTG in there. 
Does it mine automatically, or is there something i am to do to start mining?

Comment: No, the wallet doesn't mine.

Comment: Thanks very much. Somehow in exploring my mining options, i am not sure what has happened. I am now getting an error message that says. "cannot parse configuration file: the options configuration file contains aninvalid line '-zwal YOUR-BITCOIN-GOLD-WALLET.MyWorker'. Only use key value=value syntax.

I am at my wits end now.... i don't know what has happened.